# Is IQ Options trading on companies like Apple or Facebook Illegal in India?

Tags: india, options, legal

I'm asking this question because, I know that FOREX Trading in India ***is not legal***, so is it legal if we trade options on companies like **Apple** or **Facebook** using **IQ Options** or **Expert Options** or basically any *foreign broker*?

Comment: Forex is trading currencies of different countries. Options are a derivative on a stock. They are not related as you imply. What did your broker tell you?

Comment: Well, I new to this field, I assumed certain things. what is the difference between binary options and just options? are they similar?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Please [take the tour](http://money.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here. You are asking a new question. Please search the site first. [What are Binary Options?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13195/what-are-binary-options) has been asked and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No any activity that involves margin call is not permitted under [Liberalized Remittance Scheme](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10192&Mode=0#1) or FMEA. As Option trading involves margin calls; it is not allowed.

> 4. Remittances under the Scheme can be consolidated in respect of family members subject to individual family members complying with its
>      terms and conditions. However, clubbing is not permitted by other
>      family members for capital account transactions such as opening a bank
>      account/investment/purchase of property, if they are not the
>      co-owners/co-partners of the overseas bank account/
>      investment/property. Further, a resident cannot gift to another
>      resident, in foreign currency, for the credit of the latter’s foreign
>      currency account held abroad under LRS.
> 5. All other transactions which are otherwise not permissible under FEMA and those in the nature of remittance for margins or margin calls
>      to overseas exchanges/ overseas counterparty are not allowed under the
>      Scheme.

Comment: Aside question: How come some of the numbers listed under section 2 of the LRS section have (to me) bizarre commas? e.g. 1,00,000 and 2,00,000 ? It appears they should be 100,000 and 200,000?

Comment: @PeterK. India follows a different convention. 100,000 is 1,00,000 read as 1 lakh. and then 10 lakh. then 1 crore [1,00,00,000]. Essentially after thousand, we use a 2 digit separator. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: but ICICI direct has margin trading, It has options (call / put) trading, why is this legal and not IQ option? I'm confused

Comment: @Jeff can you share the link.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAOSYcPfvIo&t=559s => this dude talks about option trading, he says its just like margin. I'm totally confused

Comment: @Jeff just took a look. This is talking about Futures and Options in domestic market. This is allowed. Futures and Options in overseas market is not allowed as this can be misused or cause a large outflow of Foreign exchange that can violate the Foreign Exchange Management Act.

Comment: @Dheer Is this legal? : If I do options trading on foreign market and the profits are sent to my uncle's bank account in Australia and then he sends me some amount of money (less than $200000 according to LRS) as a gift or something else?

Comment: @Jeff A resident Indian can't do Options trading on foreign market. The reason is if you do a loss, there is additional Fx that has to be sent out that can circumvent the FMEA provision. Hence a resident Indian is barred from such activities.

Comment: @Dheer I get it, but I'm not using my money to invest, its my uncle's, its like I'm just making trades behalf of him, all the money invested is my uncle's, and all losses and profits are on him, and in return ill get some money. Is this system legal?

Comment: @Jeff Your uncle can gift you any amount without any tax liability for you in India. However if it is established that this entire arrangement was with the intent to circumvent FEMA then it is illegal. If it is established that the gift from Uncle is actually investment services you have provided to your Uncle, the income is taxable to you [of course as the trading is happening on your uncle's name; he is also liable for taxes in Australia]

Comment: @Dheer So basically, the money he earns will be taxable, and as I provide investment services, the money that I earn is also taxable, If I want to know if this is perfectly legal or not, whom should I consult? (CA, Lawyer, or any others)
Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: @Jeff A CA should be able to advise you. Note there are risks to such arrangements, if there is a huge loss how/who bears it.

Comment: @Dheer I know the risks, If there is loss, I don't pay them, my uncle does, and it doesn't involve Indian currency at all, ergo no additional FX. Thanks again for all the answers, I really appreiciate it.